# uuid.h in kernel space of OSX?

Tags: c++, c, macos, kernel, mach

After I look around, I haven't find a built in function for **UUID** creation within **OSX kernel space**. (which is limited to **Kernel.framework**)

Are there any alternatives I could use? Or should I just use time hash (MD5/SHA1)?

Comment: FWIW, if you tag questions related to OSX kernel development with the `kext` and/or `xnu` tags, those of us who monitor the tags will see them a lot sooner. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should help:

```
void uuid_generate(uuid_t out);
void uuid_generate_random(uuid_t out);
void uuid_generate_time(uuid_t out);
```

They're declared in `<uuid/uuid.h>`, and linkage is defined in Libkern.exports, i.e. your kext's `OSBundleLibraries` property must list `com.apple.kpi.libkern` - which it probably already does.